# Make new hash from {"sample" => "sample"} to {:sample => "sample"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
In condition,
COLUMN = [:id, :tag_list, :price, :url, :Perweight, :Totalweight, :memo, :created_at, :updated_at]

row = {"id"=>4, "tag_list"=>"peanuts", "price"=>100, "Totalweight"=>390, "Perweight"=>nil, "url"=>nil, "memo"=>nil, nil=>nil}

from these two conditions, I want to make above Hash Object.

{:id=>4, :tag_list=>"peanuts", :price=>100, :Totalweight"=>390, :Perweight=>nil, :url=>nil, memo=>nil}
```

I tried, like this...
at first, I make empty hash,

```
new = Hash[COLUMN.zip([])] 
p new
--->
{:id=>nil, :tag_list=>nil, :price=>nil, :url=>nil, :Perweight=>nil, :Totalweight=>nil, :memo=>nil, :created_at=>nil, :updated_at=>nil}
```

and then, I dont know how to do that,
Please give me advice?

Comment: I think the Rails' method [Hash#symbolize_keys](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/symbolize_keys) is what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you!! so much!! this is what i looking for!!

Comment: Do you want to convert all keys from strings to symbols, or just those in `COLUMN`? If the former, what's the point of defining `COLUMN`? In future, please simplify your example to the bare minimum. Here I believe two keys would be sufficient.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thank you!!! you are kind!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Symbolize Keys](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/symbolize_keys).

```
row.symbolize_keys
```

or destructively

```
row.symbolize_keys!
```